# Trigger a function when selecting a data in a dropdown menu in Vue

Tags: drop-down-menu, vue.js

I have this dropdown menu that if I click value on it, I would like to trigger a function but is not working.

```
<data-list 
      ref="UiGroupName"
      name="groupName"
      id="groupName"
      keyProperty="groupName"
      label='Group Name: '
      :options="shift_groups"
      :change="gotoGroups()"
></data-list>
```

I have also tried `@click` on `:change="gotoGroups()"` but still doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Share live demo ?

Answer (score 0):

To trigger event from child to parent you need to use `$event`

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<button @click="trigger">Trigger for Parent</button>',
  methods: {
    trigger: function () {
      this.$emit('triggerparent')
    }
  },
})
new Vue({
  el: '#counter-event-example',
  data: {
    msg: ''
  },
  methods: {
    actionParent: function () {
      console.log('Parent triggerd  at : '+(new Date()).getTime());
      this.msg = 'Parent triggerd  at : '+(new Date()).getTime();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="counter-event-example">
  <p>{{ msg }}</p>
  <child @triggerparent="actionParent"></child>
</div>
```